# Can I earn money from selling videogames?

Tags: halal-haram, sharia, work, game

I develop video games, currently studying how to do it better, and i'm worried since i heard of a legislation against selling amusement.

The thing is, i want to develop videogames to call to good morals and ideally the way of Allah SWT, or at least make games which are clean (no weird theology, no alcohol nor zina promotion, etc)

So in a way, i suspect my work would be equivalent to one who makes football balls for the kids to play.

But i wonder, since i don't want to do only because other brothers do, neither forbid myself of something that is lawfull just because some people misinterpret an ayat.

Basically i would like to know if there is firm evidence against selling normal amusement, not even too long games, or not.

Assalamu alaikum wa rahmatulahi wa barakatuhu